# UNIX Timestamp Time Difference Average MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, timestamp

I am currently working on a ticket system in which I would like to work out the average amount of time it is taking staff to respond to tickets.

I have 2 columns that hold the UNIX timestamps: timestamp (when ticket was submitted) and endstamp (when ticket was closed)

```
SELECT AVG(TIMEDIFF(endstamp,timestamp)) AS timetaken FROM `tickets`
```

I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does `TIMEDIFF()` work on timestamps? You may just want `endstamp - timestamp`.

Comment: Your right, I had done this before within AVG() and it wasn't working, it seems to be fine now though - thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the problem is that `TIMEDIFF()` returns a `TIME`, not a number of seconds that can be averaged.

Answer (score 2):

A UNIX timestamp is just a representation of a point in time as a number of seconds, so basically an integer value. On the other hand, [date function `timestampdiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) operates on  3 parameters: a unit, and two values (or expressions) of `datetime` datatype (or the-like). Your query should actually raise a syntax error, since what you are giving as first argument is not a legal unit.

If you want the difference in seconds between two UNIX timestamps, just substract them, so:

```
SELECT AVG(endstamp - timestamp) AS timetaken FROM `tickets`
```